# Opening the same window in application more than once (JavaFx in this case)

Tags: java, javafx

I have following problem: I created menu bar in my application and option to configure server name, username and password for jdbc connection in my application and when option is chosen, new window is showed, where you can put those informations. But after it opened once, if I want to open it again, my application show errors. I found a solution, but it seems inelegant and I'm wondering if there is better way to do that:
(those are only relevant parts for this case of my code)

```
    public class JDBCApp extends Application {
        GridPane connectionGrid;
        Scene connectionScene;
        Stage connectionStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        manageMainGrid();
        initMenuBar();
        initConnectionSettingsAction();

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainGrid, 1600, 1000);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(JDBCApp.class.getResource("JDBCApp.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("application");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initConnectionSettingsAction() {
        connectionSettings.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+Q"));
        connectionSettings.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                manageConnectionGrid();

                populateConnectionWindow();

                connectionStage = new Stage();                
                connectionScene = new Scene(connectionGrid, 400, 240);
                connectionScene.getStylesheets().add(JDBCApp.class.getResource("JDBCApp.css").toExternalForm());
                connectionStage.setScene(connectionScene);
                connectionStage.show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void manageConnectionGrid() {
        connectionGrid = new GridPane();
        connectionGrid.setId("grid");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            connectionGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(20));
            if (i < 12) {
                connectionGrid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(20));
            }
        }
        connectionGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    }

   private void populateConnectionWindow() {
        Label giveServerName = new Label("Give server adress:");
        GridPane.setHalignment(giveServerName, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(giveServerName, 0, 1, 20, 1);

        final TextField serverName = new TextField();
        serverName.setPromptText(SSerwer.equals("") ? "<none>" : SSerwer);
        serverName.setPrefWidth(150);
        GridPane.setHalignment(serverName, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(serverName, 4, 2, 12, 1);

        Label giveUserName = new Label("Username:");
        GridPane.setHalignment(giveUserName, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(giveUserName, 0, 4, 20, 1);

        final TextField userName = new TextField();
        userName.setPromptText(SUserName.equals("") ? "<none>" : SUserName);
        userName.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        GridPane.setHalignment(userName, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(userName, 4, 5, 12, 1);

        Label givePassword = new Label("Password:");
        GridPane.setHalignment(givePassword, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(givePassword, 0, 7, 20, 1);

        final PasswordField userPassword = new PasswordField();
        userPassword.setPromptText("Your password");
        userPassword.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        GridPane.setHalignment(userPassword, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(userPassword, 4, 8, 12, 1);

        Button submitChanges = new Button("Confirm changes");
        GridPane.setHalignment(submitChanges, HPos.CENTER);
        connectionGrid.add(submitChanges, 6, 10, 8, 1);

        submitChanges.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                SSerwer = serverName.getText();
                SUserName = userName.getText();
                SPassword = userPassword.getText();
                startConnection();
                connectionGrid.getChildren().clear();
                connectionStage.hide();

            }
        });

    }

    //MAIN NOT USED
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

So in short - I was wondering if there is more efficient way of getting rid of labels and textfields after the window is closed, and creating them again every time.
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your design is very procedural. Try to think more object-oriented.

A recurring set of GUI elements may result in an own class (inheriting from an appropriate `Node` sub-class) with the constructor doing their initialization. If this set of GUI elements (or a window, for example) is needed again, you simply instantiate this object again.

---

****EDIT**** A simple example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DemoApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Main window");
        Button openLoginWindowButton = new Button("Open another Login Dialog");
        openLoginWindowButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                new LoginWindow().show();
            }
        });
        openLoginWindowButton.setPadding(new Insets(80));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(openLoginWindowButton));
        stage.show();
    }

    class LoginWindow extends Stage {

        private LabeledTextField nameField;
        private LabeledTextField passwordField;
        private Button loginButton;

        public LoginWindow() {
            setTitle("Login");
            setScene(createScene());
            registerListeners();
        }

        private Scene createScene() {
            nameField = new LabeledTextField("Name:", false);
            passwordField = new LabeledTextField("Password:", true);
            loginButton = new Button("Submit");
            HBox bottomBox = new HBox(loginButton);
            bottomBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            VBox rootBox = new VBox(20, nameField, passwordField, bottomBox);
            rootBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            return new Scene(rootBox);
        }

        private void registerListeners() {
            loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Login attempt of " + nameField.getText());
                    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                }
            });
            // ...
        }
    }

    class LabeledTextField extends HBox {

        private TextField textField;
        private Label label;

        public LabeledTextField(String text, boolean hideInput) {
            label = new Label(text);
            textField = hideInput ? new PasswordField() : new TextField();
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            setSpacing(10);
            getChildren().addAll(label, textField);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return textField.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

- you can press the button in the main window several times to open new login windows
- the `LoginWindow` class inherits all behaviour from `Stage` class and adds some common components (implementing it in that way, you don't have to "reset" them on reusage)
- the `LabeledTextField` demonstrates a simple compound component inheriting from the layout `Node` sub-class `HBox`
- as your application grows, you should move these nested classes to separate files

Comment: I am only a beginner and don't get what you mean - especially with this inhereting. Could you give me a little example? I tried to do it without this inhereting(since I don't really know how to use it in this case), but it didn't worked out.

Comment: @Dess: I added a small example app to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help(and time). Now it's  a lot clearer to me.